# Redirect all tag pages in WordPress using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect all tag pages in my wordpress website to my blog page using .htaccess. This is my code in .htaccess -

```
Redirect 301 ^tag/(.*) /blog/
```

Unfortunately it does not work, what can be the solution for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect directive doesn't use regex, you can use RedirectMatch instead

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/tag/(.*) /blog/
```

Or

```
Redirect 301 /tag/ /blog/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/tag/$ /blog/
```